# Getting Excel to "update" or "follow" a linked Access table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I'm using Excel and Access 2007.  I'm having an issue at work and my current knowledge of Access and Excel isn't enough.  I have an Access database that has certain data in it.  I have an Excel spreadsheet that imports the data from that database (through linking), and adds three more columns.  The problem is that new rows are entered into the database every day, and when I update the link in Excel, the rows in the linked table move down accordingly, but the three Excel columns do not.  Also, I highlight certain cells and when it updates, the same (now incorrect) cells are highlighted instead of the data I wanted to highlight.  Some rows get deleted, so I can't just move the Excel columns down to where they need to be.

Can I get the three Excel columns to be linked to the exact row of data they need to be linked to so that when the linked table updates, they move or disappear accordingly?  I just need to make sure everything stays together, I'm not picky about how that's done.

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: I would upgrade Excel. The Tables functionality takes care of this issue. There is a lot of other data and analysis improvements in Excel 2013 - it should be an easy decision to upgrade after 7+ years.

Comment: I'll see if I can convince my place of work to do that, definitely.  In the mean time if there's a way to do it in 2007, I'd love to know.  Thanks

Comment: Excel 2007 should be depreciated to $0 after 7 years. So the business question is: "If we spend around USD100 on Excel 2013, will that save us USD100 of time or help us make a decision that improves our business outcomes by USD100, over the next 7 years?" If you do have an organisation or manager that answers no to that proposition, that would tell you a lot about their managerial skills and whether you are productively spending your time working for them :)

Comment: What you're describing is adding custom columns to the database. Why don't you add the three additional fields to access and maintain the data there? You can still use excel to pull the data if you want for charts or whatever you use it for.

Comment: Sun, thanks, I will probably end up doing that.  Just wanted to know if it could be done this way, as other employees that use this are more comfortable in Excel.  We will be updating to 2013 in two months, so they say.

Comment: If the highlighting is done on some uniform criteria you could use conditional formatting. Also, setting up a pivot-table might give you a more stable view of the data. Just a thought.